# Add an appender for a portion of code

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net

For a certain portion of my code, I need to log all messages to a second file, specific to each instance of the action completed in two classes.

These classes (`Parser` and `Importer`) both have the following logger definition:

```
private static ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

Both also have this method:

```
public void AddAppender(IAppender appender)
{
    ((Logger)_logger.Logger).AddAppender(appender);
}
```

The whole project (ASP.NET WebForms) logging is initialized in the AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: XmlConfigurator]
```

Now, when the user triggers a certain action, this happens:

```
var logFile = new FileInfo(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["uploadDir"] + "/" + importId + "_log.txt");
var appender = new FileAppender() {
    Threshold = Level.Info,
    Layout = new PatternLayout("%message%newline"),
    File = logFile.FullName
};

var parser = new Parser(...);
parser.AddAppender(appender);
var candidates = parser.Parse(File.ReadAllLines(uploadFile.FullName));

var importer = new Importer(...);
importer.AddAppender(appender);
importer.Import(candidates, false, ignoreWarnings.Checked);
```

My expectation would be, that a file will be created at the `logFile` location, that would contain all `INFO` and above message from either of the two classes.

This, however, is not the case - no file is created at all.

What am I doing wrong and how can I make this work?

Comment: Does calling `appender.ActivateOptions()` right after construction help? Also, is this the only part where you're using log4net or can you see it working from other places? If not, initialization may simply not be happening at all. Try using `XmlConfiguration.ConfigureAndWatch` explicitly rather than relying on assembly attributes (which are unreliable).

Comment: @JeroenMostert `ActivateOptions` did the trick! It works as expected now. PS: Why are assembly attributes unreliable? I was under the impression it was the preferred way to initialize log4net?

Comment: Because of [this](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Config_XmlConfiguratorAttribute.htm): "log4net will only look for assembly level configuration attributes once. When using the log4net assembly level attributes to control the configuration of log4net you must ensure that the first call to any of the `LoggerManager` methods is made from the assembly with the configuration attributes." This is fairly easy to get wrong in practice, especially in an ASP.NET project. Also, troubleshooting explicit initialization is way easier since you know when it's happening.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Okay, I see. Thanks for the info (and the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation of `FileAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.FileAppender.html):

> This appender will first try to open the file for writing when
>   `ActivateOptions` is called. This will typically be during
>   configuration. If the file cannot be opened for writing the appender
>   will attempt to open the file again each time a message is logged to
>   the appender. If the file cannot be opened for writing when a message
>   is logged then the message will be discarded by this appender.

This documentation is slightly ambiguous, since it seems to imply the file will be opened when you attempt to log a message in all cases, but this isn't true -- unless you call `ActivateOptions`, the appender is never considered ready for appending.